# Many-to-many relations request to DataBase

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have next models:

```
class Color(models.Model):
  color = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Color')
  code = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Code of color')

class ColorSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name of set')
    color_set = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
```

How can I get filtered colors by color_set_ID in views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what are you asking for, but if you want to filter Color by ColorSet model you can use `Color.objects.filter(colorset__id=1)` or if you want filter ColorSet by Color model you can use `ColorSet.objects.filter(color_set__id=1)`, tell me if that is what you want.

If you need all the colors you can use `ColorSet.objects.get(id=1).color_set.all()`, of course you need to get one colorset object to get all elements of that object, or `Color.objects.get(id=1).color_set_set.all()` with the another model

Comment: I know id of ColorSet, which contain Colors. I need all Colors.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you want colors that are there in `ColorSet` object, you can simply get the `ColorSet` object through 
`obj = ColorSet.objects.get(id=<the id>)` 
and then you will get all the colors in that ColorSet through
`obj.color_set`

this would give you the list of objects of `Color` related to that `ColorSet`